# Video/audio lectures on differential topology?

Tags: soft-question, differential-topology, big-list, online-resources

Do there exist decent online video lectures, or even audio lectures, covering differential topology?
I'm aware of [Milnor's talk](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/Videos/IMS/Differential_Topology/), but it is more like exposition and doesn't go very far.

Comment: If you want to go far in differential topology, looking for video lectures is not the way to go. You'll need to hit the books: begin with Guillemin and Pollack. And see this: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/13575/

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Oh I know, I own that book. I just wanted something to listen to on the train or something to reinforce things I read.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately, such things are unlikely to exist. Explaining the subject through audio only would be quite a task. Videos could exist in principle, but in practice nobody videotapes small-size classes.

Comment: Hence, a suggestion: since reading on a train is difficult / unhealthy, spend the time staring into space with a problem or two simmering in your brain. No paper or pencil, except in emergencies (like writing down a key idea).

Comment: I wonder why several users voted to closed this question as off-topic, considering that similar questions have been well-received in the past. It was even discussed [whether questions about videos should have a separate tag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15169/tag-for-videos).

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Just curious, but why is reading on a train unhealthy?

Answer (score 4):

I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXHHvoaSctc) series of video lectures on youtube that looks interesting.

From the description:

> Note: Some of you may have studied point-set topology (metric and
>   topological spaces, continuous maps, compactness, etc.). The content
>   of this course is different: it is usually called algebraic and
>   **differential topology**.