# Doubts on differential geometry from Lang's book

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I am an undergraduate self-studying Differential Geometry from Lang's book "Fundamentals of Differential Geometry". I think there will be a series of doubts from my side, starting with this one.

In the chapter on MANIFOLDS, Lang has said a lot of things which I do not understand why are true.

**Background:** Consider $X$ to be a set and $(U_i,\phi_i)$ to be a chart, where $U_i\subset X$ and $\phi_i:U_i\to E_i$ where $E_i$ is a Banach space, and $\phi_i$ is a bijection to an open set $\phi_i(U_i)$ of $E_i$.

The statements that I do not understand:

> If two charts $(U_i,\phi_i)$ and $(U_j,\phi_j)$ are such that $U_i\cap U_j$ is non-null, then by considering the derivative of $\phi_j\phi_i^{-1}:\phi_i(U_i\cap U_j)\to \phi_j(U_i\cap U_j)$, we see that $E_i$ and $E_j$ are toplinearly isomorphic i.e. there exists a continuous linear isomorphism between $E_i$ and $E_j$.

Why is this true? I know that $\phi_j\phi_i^{-1}$ is an isomorphism from $\phi_i(U_i\cap U_j)$ to $\phi_j(U_i\cap U_j)$. Why then will the two Banach spaces $E_i$ and $E_j$ be top-linearly isomorphic?

> The set of points $x\in X$ such that there exists a chart $(U_i,\phi_i)$ at $x$ such that $E_i$ is toplinearly isomorphic to a given space $E$ is both open and closed.

Why is this true?

> Therefore, on each connected component of $X$, we can assume that we have an $E-$atlas i.e. collection of charts, for some fixed $E$.

Why is this true, then? I think this has more to do with topology than differential geometry, but want to clarify.

Answer (score 6):

1) The derivative is a continuous linear map between tangent spaces. Because the map is a diffeomorphism, its derivative must be an isomorphism. The tangent space to any point of a Banach space is the Banach space itself.

2) Clearly it's open. If $x_n \to x$, and there is an $E$-chart around each $x_n$, then pick an $F$-chart around $x$. Necessarily this contains the $x_n$ for large $n$. Thus the tangent space at $x_n$ is isomorphic both to $E$ and $F$, and so $E \simeq F$ as desired.

3) A set that is both open and closed is a union of connected components.

Comment: Sorry, I have not yet encountered tangent spaces in the book. Should I then accept 1) as a statement I cannot prove and move on, or is there a different explanation?

Comment: For 2), you say $x$ is trivially open because of the existence of the chart $(U_i,\phi_i)$ where $U_i$ is an open neighborhood of $x$, am I correct?

Comment: 1) No, ignore my talk of tangent spaces. Do you understand why the derivative of a map at a single point is a map between $E_i$ and $E_j$, and why it must be an isomorphism? 2) Yes.

Comment: It is a linear map from $E_i$ to $E_j$ is all I know. but why isomorphism? Sorry if I am irritating you but I am a beginner.

Comment: Also your explanation to 2) depends on "tangent space" again.

Comment: @LandonCarter "Tangent space" in this context can just be taken to mean "The Banach space the chart is an open subset of", by definition. For (2), I'm invoking the result of (1), that two different compatible charts at the same point must be based on isomorphic Banach spaces. For (1): You have a map $df_x: E_i \to E_j$, but you also have an inverse map, $dg_{f(x)}: E_j \to E_i$. Because $fg = gf = \text{Id}$, the chain rule says that the composition of these maps is the identity, whence they are isomorphisms.

Comment: Thank you for clearing things up. I understood everything except "but you also have an inverse map". Why is the existence of this inverse map guaranteed? Is this a property of a Banach space?

Comment: @LandonCarter That's the definition of a diffeomorphism! A smooth map with a smooth inverse. The inverse to your map $\phi_j \phi_i^{-1}$ is just $\phi_i \phi_j^{-1}$.

Comment: I did not know that the derivative map is a diffeomorphism.I just knew it is continuous linear. I shall read this up then. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @LandonCarter You misunderstand me. The map $\phi_j \phi_i^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism. The argument I gave showed that if $f$ is a diffeomorphism with smooth inverse $g$, then $df_x$ is an isomorphism $E_i \to E_j$.

Comment: Oh! Yeah now this all makes sense. Indeed I misunderstood you, forgive me! And thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

As an undergraduate studying differential geometry I would highly suggest that you pick a book by a geometer or someone close to the field. As I understand, Lang was a number-theorist and wrote most of these textbooks as a challenge to himself, scratching the surface of each topic outside of his field. Some books I find useful are:

(1) Barnett and O'neill Differential Geometry (excuse my misspelling)

(2) Loring Tu Manifolds

(3) John Lee Introduction to Smooth Manifolds

Comment: Lang's book is surprisingly not bad, though somewhat terse for sure. I use it as an occasional reference. But your books are also good suggestions.

Comment: @MikeMiller Yes, I don't think his books are bad, but like you said they are good references but don't provide much insight. Since the OP is new to the topic, that's why I suggested the books I did.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestions Faraad! Yes, it is becoming quite difficult to make much progress with Lang. I liked, however, the transition from "manifold is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$" to "locally homeomorphic to a Banach space". This was something new to me. Also his category theoretic approach is sort of nice. But I think I will read John Lee's Smooth Manifolds before taking Lang again.

Comment: No problem. If you want a really precise text, which again is not for first time exploration, check out Marsden Tensor and manifolds, applications book. It will give you the same feel of Lang plus so much more.

Comment: While this post is in good will and useful for the OP, this is not answering the question and thus should not be posted as an answer. Leaving a comment would be better.

Comment: @Arctic Char. The OP is self studying. When self studying you work through a few pages of a book and if you're struggling, you seek other options. The OP clearly found this post as useful as an answer.  I really didn't think users were that picky to down vote on something which was an obvious help but okay. I also think it was too long character wise for a comment.

Comment: The fact that there is too long do not justify that it is answering the question. I again agree that this post is useful. The "correct" way is to refer the OP to some related post, for example [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13575/teaching-myself-differential-topology-and-differential-geometry). And your answer belongs there instead of here.