# Question regarding countable groups with discrete space manifold structure

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, topological-groups

Good evening !

I am studying mathematical Gauge theories from the book from Mark J.D. Hamilton's book on mathematical gauge theory.

The introduction in this book is about Lie groups and Lie algebras. I got stuck on the following example :

"Every countable group $G$ with the manifold structure as a discrete space, i.e. a countable union of isolated points, is a $0$-dimensional Lie group, because every map $G\times G \rightarrow G$ is smooth (locally constant)."

I know what a countable group is, and I think I do understand the "with the manifold structure as a discrete space" part. ( I imagine it as a mesh of points (g,h)/ g,h $\in$ $G$ and at each point we have $g+h$ / $+$ is the group operation)
However, I am having a hard time understanding the smoothness of such a structure (which I imagine as being a discrete 2D surface in a 3D space).
I would appreciate it if someone can better clarify the example to me.
(Or recommend a book that is useful for self-studying Lie groups and Lie algebras)
P.S. I am a physics student (this is why I didn't use a lot of technical terms), however I am highly interested in mathematics and I might continue later on in the domain of mathematical physics !

Thanks in advance

Edit : I would also appreciate it if someone could give me an example of a $0$-dimensional Lie group

Comment: Do you know what a smooth manifold is?

Comment: No, other than the definition I just read (and understood on google ), I don't know what a smooth manifold is.

Comment: Well, a Lie group is a smooth manifold with additional structure, so I recommend you learn about smooth manifolds first. Moreover, if you want to learn gauge theory, you need to have a solid understanding of smooth manifolds. There are many excellent books for this, my suggestion is Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, but there are many others, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13575/39599).

Comment: To understand smooth manifolds do I need some knowledge in differential geometry (and some topology) ?

Comment: Yes. Differential geometry is the study of smooth manifolds.