# Differential Geometry's lecture notes by professor Will Merry

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request

I have recently got to know these notes from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3622072/368425) answer, i.e.,

> Will Merry, [Differential Geometry](https://www.merry.io/differential-geometry/): beautifully written notes (with problems sheets!), where lectures 1-27 cover pretty much the same stuff as the above book of Jeffrey Lee. Lectures 28-53 also center around metrics and connections, but the notion of parallel transport is worked out much more thoroughly than in Jeffrey Lee's book.

It's unfortunate that the author passed away and the link (to the notes given in that answer) does not work anymore.

I would like to ask if someone keeps these notes and can share them. Thank you so much!

Comment: https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~pmhw/DG2007.pdf  although it seems you are asking for something more basic

Comment: The notes from 2007 appear to be notes Merry put in order from a course he took as a student.  He taught at ETH Zurich (from what I've traced) and a set of notes that seem to be from _that_ course are on a Brazilian archive: https://www.passeidireto.com/arquivo/104639169/differential-geometry-will-merry-ethz-2021/13  .  There are "protected" videos from a course of his at https://video.ethz.ch/lectures/d-math/2020/autumn/401-3531-00L.html   .  Perhaps someone will extract the notes at his .io site and make them available posthumously.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ETH Zürich has created a [website](https://www2.math.ethz.ch/will-merry/index.html) in memory of professor Will Merry. You can find the complete set of his lecture notes on Differential Geometry there.

Comment: Thanks!  Somehow my search didn't turn this up, even though it's been around since last autumn.  (I was looking specifically for the notes and not more broadly for the author.)