# Learning Riemannian Geometry

Tags: riemannian-geometry, self-learning, online-resources, lecture-notes

I would like to add standard knowledge from a first Riemannian geometry class to my tool belt. Textbooks are great, but I often find I have trouble knowing what topics to focus on and what topics a professor might just glaze over. So I find myself spending too much time on less important topics and, some times, not enough time on the important topics. Moreover, I often find there are too many exercises for me to do all of them, and I struggle to pick out a handful which would be most conducive to my learning. Ultimately, this probably points to a personal shortcoming in my independent learning skills.

Either way, I was hoping someone might be able to recommend a free lecture series (or lecture notes) on Riemannian geometry with publicly available homework problems. Thanks!

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4663144/differential-geometrys-lecture-notes-by-professor-will-merry) may be useful for you.